# Part of the label clickable and bold at the same time

Tags: swift, string, uilabel, clickable, nsmutableattributedstring

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    @discardableResult
    public func setAsLink(textToFind: NSMutableAttributedString, linkURL: String) -> Bool {

        let foundRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind)
        if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURL, range: foundRange)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}



@IBDesignable
class SignUpLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let normalText = "Don't have an account yet? "
        let normalString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: normalText)

        let boldText  = "Sign up now!"
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: boldText, attributes: attrs)

        normalString.append(attributedString)

        self.attributedText = normalString

        normalString.setAsLink(textToFind: attributedString, linkURL: "http://www.someaddress.com")

    }

}
```

`let foundRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind)` requires String but I have declared it as a NSMutableAttributedString so I would be able to add weight to specific part of the label.

I can't figure it out. Can somebody please help me with the fix? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableAttributedString` has a property called `string`. To access it, and allow for searching, use `yourMutableAttributedString.string` as the argument.